# Runnable stopped when activity is paused

Tags: android, runnable

I have a clock done by updating a TextView text using a Runnable. When I'm in the Activity the TextView is updated properly, but when I leave and come back to the activity, the code in the `run()` method is not executed anymore.

Do I have to call `run()` again in the `onResume` of my activity? Why? Is the mTicker Runnable stopped?

**MyActivity.java**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mHandler = new Handler();

    mTicker = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if(mClockStopped) return;
            long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
            mCalendar.setTimeInMillis(now);  
            mClock.setText(DateFormat.format("kk:mm", mCalendar));
            mClock.invalidate();
            long upTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
            long next = upTime + (60000 - now % 60000);
            mHandler.postAtTime(mTicker, next);
        }
    };
    mTicker.run();

    /* more stuff */

}

@Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        mClockStopped = false; 
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause()
    {
        mClockStopped = true;        
        super.onPause();
    }
```

Comment: I'd say it's because your run() method exits if the mClockStopped flag is set :-)

Comment: Not to be a wise-ass but if you'd actually written the code yourself, you would've known that the problem was what @fedepaol is suggesting. This should be a reminder to not just blindly copy-pasting code from someone else ;-)

Comment: Ok, 'return' exits the method! Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe is not that simple, but setting mClockStopped to true make your runnable's run() exit.

You should call

```
mClockStopped = false; 
mTicker.run();
```

In `onResume`